# HBase region servers keeps crashing on tsv import

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

Am trying to load **tab** separated HDFS file (**3.5G**) with **45 Million record** into HBASE, using the below command

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,description:part_description part /user/sw/spark_search/part_description_data
```

**file snippet**

```
45-573  Conn Circular Adapter F/M 11 POS ST 1 Port
CA3100E14S-4P-B-03  Conn Circular PIN 1 POS Crimp ST Wall Mount 1 Terminal 1 Port Automotive
```

I can see a map reduce job starts and reaches 5% and but then the region servers just crashes and job timeouts.
and throws

```
19/06/26 14:56:31 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
19/06/26 15:06:59 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1561551541629_0001_m_000010_0, Status : FAILED
AttemptID:attempt_1561551541629_0001_m_000010_0 Timed out after 600 secs
19/06/26 15:06:59 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1561551541629_0001_m_000004_0, Status : FAILED
AttemptID:attempt_1561551541629_0001_m_000004_0 Timed out after 600 secs
19/06/26 15:06:59 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1561551541629_0001_m_000003_0, Status : FAILED
AttemptID:attempt_1561551541629_0001_m_000003_0 Timed out after 600 secs
```

after I restart the server I can see some of the data has already been loaded, how can I trace the cause of the crash ?

After checking regionservers logs, the only error I can see is

```
2019-06-27 15:43:05,361 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer: Unexpected throwable object 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ResultOrException$Builder.buildPartial(ClientProtos.java:29885)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ResultOrException$Builder.build(ClientProtos.java:29877)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.getResultOrException(RSRpcServices.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.getResultOrException(RSRpcServices.java:319)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.doBatchOp(RSRpcServices.java:789)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.doNonAtomicRegionMutation(RSRpcServices.java:716)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.multi(RSRpcServices.java:2146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:33656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:163)
2019-06-27 15:43:08,120 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.5-cdh5.14.4--1, built on 06/12/2018 10:49 GMT
```

But I can see I had enough free RAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused due to Heap memory overflow, the default value set by cloudera seems to be low, after increasing heap to 4G the file was successfully loaded

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your mappers are taking longer than 600 seconds to run, and so timeout and die. Set `mapreduce.task.timeout` to `0`. Normally this wouldn't be a problem, but in your case the job writes to HBase and not the normal MapReduce `context.write(...)`, and so MapReduce thinks nothing is happening.

See https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml.

Comment: I did check and it's set to 10 minutes, I have updated it to 0, yet I think the opposite is happening, the region server crashes first, this is why mapReduce timeouts

Comment: I tried again and it seems as I imagined, the region server fails and crashes after 20 seconds of processing, and then the mappers timesout after 10 minutes as expected

Comment: I checked region servers logs, please check edited question